# Unity2D - Rigidbody not stopping when it reaches a position

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I have this code:

```
public class MoveCard : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 1f;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Vector2 pos = new Vector2(6.8f,0);
public bool move = false;
void FixedUpdate(){
    if (move){
           //Stops Rigidbody
           if (rb.position == pos){
               move = false;
            }
            rb.transform.position += -rb.transform.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;      
    }
}
public void CardMovement(){
    move = true;
}
}
```

I have it set as so when a button is pressed, CardMovement() initiates and in FixedUpdate I have a if statement that turns move off when the Rigidbody reaches a certain position. The rb moves but it doesn't stop when it reaches the Vector2. I am new to Unity so I don't know if this is the way to do it.

Comment: I don't believe `rb.position == pos` will every really be true.  What I mean is rb.position moves every `fixedDeltaTime` by a certain amount so `Vector2(12.092, 8.128)` will never be equal to `Vector2(12, 8)` (made up numbers).  You need to test for **equivalence** or `>=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare the 2 vector2D values like this:

```
if(rb.position == pos)
```

Rather compare the distance between them with a value that is very small, like this:

```
if(Vector2.Distance(rb.position,pos) <= 0.01)
```

Additionally, you can set the position like this `rb.postion = pos;` if it is close enough so that it snaps to the right location.

Comment: It works when the speed is set to 1, but it keeps moving when I set to 2. Why is that and is there a fix?

Comment: The problem is that when you alter the position of a transform directly, it does not move to the new position bu rather jumps to it, skipping everything in between.

When you move at a speed of 2 you are skipping bigger parts at a time and thus skipping over the point, never reaching close enough.

Comment: A solution could be to scale the 0.01 value up with your speed, use a bigger value, or move in a different way.

Comment: Try with MoveTowards, thats where MoveTowards is used. Distance is a hight cost Method because it uses square roots and your gameObject will not stop exactly at the point, will stop at the ponit +/-0.01 distance or the number your putting at the statement.

Comment: @RubénCantón I hear you and agree that it is expensive because of the square root. By setting the rb.poistion to pos when close enough it snaps to correct position once it stops.

Comment: If you want to use distance. Think about distance(vA, vB) is the same than (vA-vB).magnitude you can use (vA-vB).sqrmagnitude in order to avoid this square root and make the program more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Well your Rb doesn't pass exactly for each point between the initial position and Vector2.
It's prtty unlikely to have rb.position == pos because one frame it will not enough, and the next one will be too much :)

Try with MoveTowards. Some like this:

```
rb.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb.position, pos, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

You dont need a statement to stop it because it will do it when reaches pos.

PD: You can do this with transform instead of rigidbody if u are not going to use physics and you only want a movement.